# How to track the location of the devices using myapp

Tags: ios, gps

How to track  the location of the devices using myapp which are moving in a car .its need for social networking pupose.?

Answer (score 1):

You Must need a web service that stores locations of devices when the app is running, then from your app send a query to the webservice from there you will find the list of device using he app in a range .

Comment: Just a note I want to add. I went down this path. It's not a very elegant solution since the user is always polling the server and the web request can fail more often than you'd want. I heard about socket programming where the user keeps a live connection to the server and when ever the server changes, the user is notified, sounds more like the right approach but also sounds much harder :P